# Apple ID through OAuth?

Tags: android, ios, oauth

I was using Facebook login and other 3rd Party login in mobile game based on the way that,

1. client integrates Native Facebook SDK (or other native sdk)
2. client login and get OAuth access token
3. client pass access token to server side and server makes a server-side authentication to Facebook
4. if server side get FB Uid, then based on it creates an account or login to existing account for the user.

My question is, in order to free user from login to service every time, is it possible to directly use Apple ID on the device for such flow of authentication? What about Android and Google ID? Or other type of solutions I should look into?

Answer (score 11):

I know the question is old, but it's one of the first that get get listed when searching for "apple oauth"...

Apple has anounced at the [WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/) a new feature called **[Sign in with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/)** which allows you to use oauth for apple logins like facebook, twitter, google etc. Developer resources can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/resources/) and a good introduction [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple).

Comment: how to do it with android app? I can't find SDK for sign in or normal documentation like Facebook for example has https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/

Answer (score 4):

————- update: ————————————————

We now have Sign-In with Apple: https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/

—————— old version —————————————

For apple user accounts there is no oAuth 'ID'-provider

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6594633?start=0&tstart=0
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_OAuth_providers

My personal opinion about that fact is the following.
Apple wants to sell hardware. If software is needed to support that, they implement or buy it.

Apple might be wrong, as web apps are integrating Facebook, Google, Twitter, Windows Live and sometimes Weibo, LinkedIn or Amazon oAuth.
I never heard about plans for oAuth for Apple ID.

Comment: Looks like this might have changed as of yesterday?

Comment: Yep, I found the following article helpful https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple