# What is the best way to auth users in iOS app with backend?

Tags: ios, authentication

I write iOS app with server side (let's say chat or whatever that requires authentication).

And I would like user to be able to use multiple devices with easy as possible authentication process (the best one – without visible process at all).

Basically user is already authenticated in iOS (with his/her apple ID).

So, for my opinion, authentication could be easy like this:

1) Get current user ID from iOS (it does not have to be an apple ID itself, but any string that is not changing within a single apple ID within my own app).

2) Get some signature from iOS for this apple ID to have an ability to verify that string (1) is valid on a server side (otherwise client can send any random string).

Pros: 99% of users are already authenticated and user have nothing to do. No email required or whatever. And it's secure. For 1% who not authenticated - they can just do it in iOS.

Unfortunately I did not find something like this.

Solutions I considered that I don't like:

1) My own auth.
Cons: Every single user must register, set up email (in order to have an ability to recovery password), chose password, etc. I believe that half of users can just delete app to avoid this hell.

2) Social network auth. Cons: Bunch of different buttons that does not look cool at all. Difficult to integrate and support each of them. And still there is a chance that user does not have all this twitter/facebook/etc accounts and still (1) required.

3) Game Center auth. Cons: Actually it's OK, something little bit similar to my ideal one, but the main issue with it - how can I guarantee on my back end that user with GC ID "G:123456789" that sent request is not fake one? Cause he can send any ID he want and I can't find a way to verify it.

Is there any good way not to bother user too much and still have convenient and secure auth method?

Comment: For privacy reasons, Apple does not provide a method for indentifying the AppleID that is being used on a particular device; not even an opaque identifier since that could be used for tracking the user across devices.  You will need to use option 1 (you can allow people to use option 2 if they like but use of a social login should be optional)

Comment: partially a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171174/apple-id-through-oauth